# StackOverflow Careers candidate search user guide uses the term "hone in on" when it should be "home in on"

Tags: bug, jobs, grammar

In the [StackOverflow Careers candidate search user guide](http://blog.careers.stackoverflow.com/2013/11/01/candidate-search-user-guide/) under the heading tips on maximising search results we have the following sentence

> Our goal with the candidate search on Stack Overflow Careers is to make it easy for you to **hone in on** specific criteria so you can expedite your hiring process and avoid sorting through hundreds of candidate profiles that don’t meet your needs.

However you can't "hone in on" anything. You can "hone a sword" i.e. sharpen it to improve it and "honing a skill" is a simple extension of that idea.

You can however "home in on" something, like a guided missile homes in on its target.

There are some more details on [home/hone confusion here](http://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/hone-vs-home) and if you want a [Stack Exchange reference, try this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32684/which-is-correct-home-in-or-hone-in).

It seems we should have this instead then

> Our goal with the candidate search on Stack Overflow Careers is to make it easy for you to home in on specific criteria so you can expedite your hiring process and avoid sorting through hundreds of candidate profiles that don’t meet your needs.

Comment: Not sure I agree with the SE reference there. It may originally have been "home in on" but common usage dictates otherwise... It's been used since at least 1965, see http://i.word.com/idictionary/hone%20in

Comment: It certainly is a pretty common and widespread mistake.My research suggested that its more common in America which my be why it sounded so odd when I read it.